# Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: database, ms-access, syntax

I tried out to connect my database(ms-access) to Visual basic.But it came up with the following error:

```
    A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

    Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

    If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

I used the following code.please see if there is any error..please help me out for it..
The Code is:

```
    Private Sub frmGive_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\AntivirUS Vandry\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Give And Get\dbaseMain.mdb")
    Dim sql As String = "Select * from tblGive"
    Dim dbcmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    con.Open()
    Dim dbadapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    Dim db As DataSet = New DataSet("TABLE")
    dbadapter.Fill(db, "TABLE")
    'create new instance of table so that row can be accessed
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt = db.Tables("TABLE")
    CmbGenre.Text = dt.Rows(0)(0)
    CmbLanguage.Text = dt.Rows(0)(1)
    txtNMovie.Text = dt.Rows(0)(2)
    txtFName.Text = dt.Rows(0)(3)
    txtLname.Text = dt.Rows(0)(4)
    CmbClass.Text = dt.Rows(0)(5)
    txtnull.Text = dt.Rows(0)(6) 
End Sub
```

There are some codes in between them.Including textboxes and combo boxes.

```
    Public Sub submit()
    con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\AntivirUS Vandry\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Give And Get\dbaseMain.mdb")
    con.Open()

    Dim sql As String
    sql = "Insert into tblGive (Genre,Language,NMovie,FName,LName,Class,SaveDate)" + "VALUES (" & CmbGenre.Text & "','" & CmbLanguage.Text & "','" & txtNMovie.Text & "','" & txtFName.Text & "','" & txtLname.Text & "','" & CmbClass.Text & "','" & txtnull.Text & "')"
    MsgBox(sql)
    Dim dbcmd As OleDbCommand
    dbcmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Saved")
End Sub
```

Comment: be sure that you are not using any keyword as column name in the table

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a single quote at the beginning of the `values` keyword.

In other words,

```
VALUES (" & CmbGenre.Text & "','" & CmbLanguage.Text &
```

should be

```
VALUES ('" & CmbGenre.Text & "','" & CmbLanguage.Text &
```